# Acionar alert utilizando Selenium em Java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver

Além de manipular alertas javascript com *Selenium WebDriver*, seria possível invocar alertas em tempo de execução do código Selenium no navegador?

Gostaria de criar os 3 tipos de alerta javascript abaixo usando *selenium*:

- `alerta`
- `confirmação`
- `prompt de entrada.`

*Para facilitar o entendimento...*

Ao acessar uma página qualquer (*usei w3c como exemplo*) com *Selenium*:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/JS/");
```

Quero invocar os 3 tipos de alerta abaixo com valores dinâmicos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que com JavaScript da pra fazer, algo como:

```
driver.executeScript("window.alert('teste')")
String confirmation = driver.executeScript("return window.confirm('confirmação')");
String result = driver.executeScript("return prompt('Por favor, insira seu nome:', 'Harry Potter')");
```

Fonte:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp

Comment: Show de bola cara, era isso mesmo!

Answer (score 2):

Algo legal de se deixar anotado caso alguém procure também. Estava com duvidas como passar pelo alert. Achei o seguinte script que deu certo:

```
    // pega o alert que está aberto
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    // confirma
    alert.accept();
```

Funcionou! Achei o script por um curso do Alura referente a selenium.

Answer (score 0):

para interagir com os alerts eu faço o seguinte

Assim como @João

```
// pega o alert que está aberto
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    // confirma
    alert.accept();
```

Mas também acrescento:

```
    // aperta o cancelar
      alert.dismiss();
   // escreve no prompt
      alert.sendKeys("Escrevi no prompt");
```

Referencia:

[Documentação selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/js_alerts_prompts_and_confirmations/)